# Web API Route 404: "No action was found on the controller that matches"

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-web-api

I keep getting a 404 and cannot see why?

**GLOBAL.ASAX:**

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // GetApi - Allows for:
    // - GET: With or without an Id (because id is marked as 'optional' in defaults)
    RouteTable.Routes.MapHttpRoute(name: "GetApi",
                               routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                               defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });

    // ActionsApi - Allows for:
    // - CREATE
    // - DELETE
    // - SAVE
    // - UPDATE
    // - LIST
    // - FIND
    // - and many, many more
    RouteTable.Routes.MapHttpRoute(name: "ActionsApi",
                       routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/actions/{action}",
                       defaults: new { });

    // QueryByNameApi - Allows for:
    // - FIND: By-Name (within the URL...not the data)
    RouteTable.Routes.MapHttpRoute(name: "QueryByNameApi",
                                   routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/actions/by-name/{value}",
                                   defaults: new
                                   {
                                       value = "",
                                       action = "QueryByName"
                                   });
}
```

**CONTROLLER:**

```
public class SearchController : ApiController
{
    internal const string MSG_UNMANAGEDEXCEPTION = "An unexpected error occurred. Please try again.";

    // THIS WORKS !!!
    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage Hello()
    {
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Hello back!");
    }

    // BUT...THIS FAILS ???
    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage Find(string value)
    {
        var result = new SearchResult();

        try
        {
            var term = value.ToLowerInvariant().Trim();
            var query = Mock.Categories();

            // WHERE
            query = query.Where(x => x.Name.ToLowerInvariant().Trim().Contains(term)
                                  || x.categoryType.Name.ToLowerInvariant().Trim().Contains(term));

            // ORDER BY
            query = query.OrderBy(x => x.Name)
                         .ThenBy(x => x.categoryType.Name);

            // MATERIALIZED
            var collection = query.ToList();

            result.Filters = collection.Select(x => x.categoryType).ToList();
            result.Records = collection;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            HttpError error = new HttpError(MSG_UNMANAGEDEXCEPTION);
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, error);
        }

        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, result);
    }
}
```

**JAVASCRIPT:**
The POST fails...

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    data: { "value": text },
    url: 'api/search/actions/find',
    contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
})
```

But the GET succeeds?...

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    data: {},
    url: 'api/search/actions/hello',
    contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `by-name` in the `routeTemplate` of `QueryByNameApi` with `{action}` and in `SearchController` add `[Route("api/search/actions/find/{value:string}")]` attribute to the `Find()` method

Edit:

If you want to match `ActionsApi` try executing this ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    data: { value: text },
    url: 'api/search/actions/find',
    contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
})
```

else if you want to match `QueryByNameApi` try:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'api/search/actions/find/' + value,
    contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
})
```

Comment: Shouldn't the "ActionsApi" take precedence over the "QueryByNameApi"?

Comment: Also, why do I have to "further define" the route in the controller with the [Route] attribute?  Isn't that the job of the "RouteTable"?

Comment: It should take precedence when executing your second ajax call. But I think that you should type the `url` like `url: 'api/search/actions/find/' + value` in the first ajax call.

Comment: Yes, but I like to put this attribute just to be sure that everything will match as expected, but at the end you decide

Comment: I even commented-out the "QueryByNameApi" entirely & reset IIS

Comment: Well, I once got such a strange behavior and I managed to solve it by (in your case) replacing all `value` params and arguments with `id`. But I am not sure if that would work.

Comment: UPDATED THE QUESTION: The 'get' succeeds...only the post fails.

Comment: Your `GET` request obviously matches `ActionsApi` try adding `data:{ value: text }` again and make it `POST`

Comment: "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:60416/api/search/actions/find"
"No action was found on the controller 'Search' that matches the request."

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be sending json data in your post however you have set your content type to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.
I would define a new class to hold your post values and redefine your post action.

```
public class PostData
{
    public string value { get; set; }
}
```

Controller Action:

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage Find(PostData Data)
{
    string term = Data.value;

    //... implementation excluded
}
```

Then change your ajax call.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    data: { "value": text },
    url: 'api/search/actions/find',
    contentType: 'application/json'
})
```